# Macro to create new rows in separate tab based on qty in cell

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a tab (data tab) in excel where users can paste in a list of products that need to be ordered in column 'A' and the qty of each product in column 'B'.

I'm trying to create a macro that will look at the qty in column 'B' of each row and create that many records into a new tab (upload tab).

ie.

Data Tab

[image: Data Tab]

Desired Results

[image: Desired results in (upload tab)]

Comment: You should attach the images inline instead of providing the links to images.

Answer (score 0):

Create an activex button, put this code on it. If the Upload sheet doesnt exist, it is created, otherwise it clears everything before executing the code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lastrow2 As Long
    Dim row As Long
    Dim product As String
    Dim count As Long
    Dim repeat As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    If Evaluate("ISREF('" & "Upload" & "'!A1)") = False Then
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.count))
        ws.Name = "Upload"
    End With
    Else
        Sheets("Upload").UsedRange.ClearContents
    End If
    Set ws = Sheets("Upload")
    ws.Cells(1, 1) = "Product"
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    lastrow2 = ws.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    For row = 2 To lastrow
        product = Cells(row, 1)
        count = Cells(row, 2)
            For repeat = 1 To count
                lastrow2 = lastrow2 + 1
                ws.Cells(lastrow2, 1) = product
            Next repeat
    Next row

End Sub
```